# How to extract multiple hashtags from a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to extract "animal" and "fish" hashtags from the JSON object below. I know how to extract the first instance named "animal", but I have no idea how to extract both instances. I was thinking to use a loop, but unsure where to start with it. Please advise.

```
data = '{"hashtags":[{"text":"animal","indices":[5110,1521]},
        {"text":"Fish","indices":[122,142]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":
        [{"screen_name":"test241","name":"Test 
        Dude","id":4999095,"id_str":"489996095","indices":[30,1111]},
        {"screen_name":"test","name":"test","id":11999991,
        "id_str":"1999990", "indices":[11,11]}],"urls":[]}'; 

function showHashtag(data){
   i = 0;
   obj = JSON.parse(data); 
   console.log(obj.hashtags[i].text);
}

showHashtag(data);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let data = '{"hashtags":[{"text":"animal","indices":[5110,1521]},{"text":"Fish","indices":[122,142]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"test241","name":"Test Dude","id":4999095,"id_str":"489996095","indices":[30,1111]},   {"screen_name":"test","name":"test","id":11999991,        "id_str":"1999990", "indices":[11,11]}],"urls":[]}';

function showHashtag(data){
    return JSON.parse(data).hashtags.filter(e => /animal|fish/i.test(e.text))
}

console.log(showHashtag(data));
```

To make the function reusable, in case you want to find other "hashtags", you could pass an array like so:

```
function showHashtag(data, tags){
    let r = new RegExp(tags.join("|"), "i");
    return JSON.parse(data).hashtags.filter(e => r.test(e.text))
}

console.log(showHashtag(data, ['animal', 'fish']));
```

To get only the text property, just chain map()

```
console.log(showHashtag(data, ['animal', 'fish']).map(e => e.text));
```

or in the function

```
return JSON.parse(data).hashtags
    .filter(e => /animal|fish/i.test(e.text))
    .map(e => e.text);
```

EDIT:

I don't really get why you would filter by animal and fish if all you want is an array with `['animal', 'fish']`. To only get the objects that have a text property, again, use filter, but like this

```js
let data = '{"hashtags":[{"text":"animal","indices":[5110,1521]},{"text":"Fish","indices":[122,142]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"test241","name":"Test Dude","id":4999095,"id_str":"489996095","indices":[30,1111]},   {"screen_name":"test","name":"test","id":11999991,        "id_str":"1999990", "indices":[11,11]}],"urls":[]}';

function showHashtag(data){
    return JSON.parse(data).hashtags
      .filter(e => e.text)
      .map(e => e.text);
}

console.log(showHashtag(data));
```

Comment: an short explanation of `filter` method might be nice since OP does not seems to be that much familliar to javascript.

Comment: @baao thank you for the advice and answer, but I would like to extract and print the text only i.e. ["animal", "fish"]. Can I use filter to do this?

Comment: Added that @jr134.

Comment: But why do you search for that? Do you want to have the objects with a `text` property only? @jr134

Comment: @baao I am learning much here, but what I forgot to mention was that I have multiple objects like this which have different hashtags, which I don't think a filter would work with. Apologies for my initial explanation, as I did not outline this.

Comment: @baao thank you for the answer, much appreciated. I have got much learning to do using JavaScript :-)

Answer (score 1):

For me, [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) can be of great use here, which have different functions in terms of collections. For your case i'd use `_.find` function to help check the array and get any of the tags with the creteria passed in as second argument like so:

> *.find(collection, [predicate=*.identity], [fromIndex=0])
>   source npm package
>
> Iterates over elements of collection, returning the first element
>   predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three
>   arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

with your case this should work

```
var data = '{ "hashtags": [ { "text": "animal", "indices": [ 5110, 1521 ] }, { "text": "Fish", "indices": [ 122, 142 ] } ], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [ { "screen_name": "test241", "name": "Test \n Dude", "id": 4999095, "id_str": "489996095", "indices": [ 30, 1111 ] }, { "screen_name": "test", "name": "test", "id": 11999991, "id_str": "1999990", "indices": [ 11, 11 ] } ], "urls": [] }'; 

var obj = JSON.parse(data); 


_.find(obj.hashtags, { 'text': 'animal' });
// => { "text": "animal", "indices": [ 5110, 1521 ] }
```

Comment: is there `_.find` function in javascript?

Comment: oh no, it's a function in lodash library, which gives different room for manipulating objects,arrays and so on

Comment: And still `_.find()` does only return the first suitable occurrence. While OP wanted to return more than one element.

Comment: And further a simple `obj.hashtags.find(elem => elem.text === 'animal');`
 gives the same result as your lodash solution and does not need any additional third party library...

Comment: `_.filter` can do just well in this case, and don't get this wrong it just a way to  make your code neater instead having to do all these. @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

For simple parsing like this one, I would use the plain old `obj.forEach()` method, it is more readable and easy to understand, especially for javascript beginner.

```
obj = JSON.parse(data).hashtags;
obj.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element['text']);
});
```